# How to select dropdown option with javascript and change his value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got a dropdown and I need to put values in there that need to be escaped with javascript.

The reason why I want to use javascript is because the api I query is working with javascript and don't receive the other ways to escape quotes.

Exemple of dropdown value : `"ToxKeywords:"genotoxicity" AND ToxKeywords:"ames" OR ToxKeywords:"micronucleus""`

So i got this dropdown :

```
<form method="post" name="query">
    <label for="textQuery">Choose Query from list</label>
    <select class="form-control space" name="textQuery" id="textQuery">
        <option selected disabled>Choose here</option>
        <option value="ToxKeywords:">ToxKeywords</option>
        <option value="Molecules.Main_name:">Molecule</option>
        <option value="Query1">Query 1</option>
        <option value=ToxKeywords:systemic toxicity>Query 2</option>
        <option value=ToxKeywords:"phototoxicity">Query 3</option>
        <option value=ToxKeywords:"llna">Query 4</option>
    </select>
```

And i want to replace for exemple `value="Query1"` with javascript.
I tried this :

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("textQuery").selectedindex = "Query 1"
    select.option.value = "ToxKeywords:\"genotoxicity\" AND ToxKeywords:\"ames\" OR ToxKeywords:\"micronucleus\"";
</script>
```

Apparently i can select the right value but i don't know how to change it to : `"ToxKeywords:\"genotoxicity\" AND ToxKeywords:\"ames\" OR ToxKeywords:\"micronucleus\""`

Can you help me to find the right `Javascript` syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: [document.querySelector(selectors);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```js
document.querySelector('#textQuery option[value="Query1"]').value =
           'http://130.88.150.30:8983/solr/NCSTOX/select?indent=on&q=Tox‌​Keywords:%22genotoxi‌​city%22%20AND%20ToxK‌​eywords:%22ames%22%2‌​0OR%20ToxKeywords:%2‌​2micronucleus%22&wt=‌​json and i got : http://130.88.150.30:8983/solr/NCSTOX/select?indent=on&amp;q‌​=ToxKeywords:&quot;g‌​enotoxicity&quot; AND ToxKeywords:&quot;ames&quot; OR ToxKeywords:&quot;micronucleus&quot;&amp;rows=10&amp;wt=json';
            
document.getElementById('textQuery').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  console.log(this.value);
})
```

```html
<form method="post" name="query">
    <label for="textQuery">Choose Query from list</label>
    <select class="form-control space" name="textQuery" id="textQuery">
        <option selected disabled>Choose here</option>
        <option value="ToxKeywords:">ToxKeywords</option>
        <option value="Molecules.Main_name:">Molecule</option>
        <option value="Query1">Query 1</option>
        <option value=ToxKeywords:systemic toxicity>Query 2</option>
        <option value=ToxKeywords:"phototoxicity">Query 3</option>
        <option value=ToxKeywords:"llna">Query 4</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you your code is good so i valid it but i doesn't solve my problem as the html query should be `http://130.88.150.30:8983/solr/NCSTOX/select?indent=on&q=ToxKeywords:%22genotoxicity%22%20AND%20ToxKeywords:%22ames%22%20OR%20ToxKeywords:%22micronucleus%22&wt=json` and i got : `http://130.88.150.30:8983/solr/NCSTOX/select?indent=on&amp;q=ToxKeywords:&quot;genotoxicity&quot; AND ToxKeywords:&quot;ames&quot; OR ToxKeywords:&quot;micronucleus&quot;&amp;rows=10&amp;wt=json`

Comment: I found it. It was document.querySelector('#textQuery option[value="Query1"]').value ='ToxKeywords:%22genotoxicity%22%20AND%20ToxKeywords:%22ames%22%20OR%20ToxKeywords:%22micronucleus%22'